# How Do I Add Images To My Blog Posts?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and followed [djangogirls.com](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) tutorial that makes a blog. In the model of a (blog) post there is a `TextField` that contains a post's text. However, I am trying to make it so that I can put a variable number of pictures within that text, and at any position within it.

I wrote `HTML` into a blog's text and used template tags to turn off auto-escaping. This allowed me to include images wherever I wanted, but I want to know if there is a better way to implement this? Even if someone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm happy to post code, I just didn't know what code would be helpful.

Comment: Try looking at some of the ['wysiwyg' editor packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/) for django, that's your best option.

Comment: There are too many available options, from installing any one of the available wyswig editor packages to building your own (at least the django / editor binding).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some rich text editor for that like`wyswig` or `ckeditor`.

Here I am using **ckeditor**

First install `ckeditor`

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

Then,

**project settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    . . . .
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    . . . . 
]

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
     },
}
```

**project urls.py** add

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

**app models.py**

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

text = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Why specifically ckeditor ? There are others legitimate options, and FWIW neither the OP nor anyone else reading this question will learn anything from your answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I was saying that he can use some rich text editor

Comment: @RobertBain, If the solution worked for you, please vote up and select the answer. If any problem comment it below. Thanks a lot for all the cooperation.